# How to export all tables from a database ordered by a common column?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, export-to-csv, information-schema

I want to export each table from a database to a separated csv file ordered by a commom column to all tables. I'm using MySql, phpMyAdmin and Windows 10

I'm a newbie in MySql and searching on Stackoverflow I could get to this code that exports one table to a csv file, exactly as I want:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'c://path/name_of_table.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
FROM `name_of_table` ORDER BY name_of_column;
```

Could I iterate over all tables from a specific database using the table name as a variable in my above query?

Something like:

```
FOREACH my_table IN my_database

    SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'c://path/' .my_table.table_name. '.csv'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
    FROM `my_table.table_name` ORDER BY name_of_column;

END FOREACH;
```

Any other approach is also wellcome

Thanks!

Comment: you could do a sql dump of the database if then you are going to reload everything in a new database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were halfway there.

One solution would be to use a stored procedure with a cursor to get the table names and some dynamic SQL to make the SELECT INTO OUTFILE statement.

Something like this should work.

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS db_export_csv //
CREATE PROCEDURE db_export_csv(_path VARCHAR(255), _sname VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN
  DECLARE tname VARCHAR(64);
  DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;

  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT `table_name`
    FROM `information_schema`.`tables`
    WHERE `table_schema` = _sname
    AND `table_type` = 'BASE TABLE';

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done = TRUE;
  OPEN cur;

  myloop: LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO tname;
    IF done THEN 
      LEAVE myloop; 
    END IF;

    SET @sql = CONCAT("SELECT * INTO OUTFILE \'" , _path , '' , tname , '_' , CURRENT_DATE , ".csv\' ",
      "FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ", 
      "OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '''' ",
      "LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ", 
      "FROM `" , _sname , "`.`" , tname , "` ORDER BY `yrcolname` ASC");

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

  END LOOP; 

END //

DELIMITER ;

CALL db_export_csv('/var/lib/mysql-files/', 'test');
```

Obviously, I've tested it on Linux, so you would put your own writable path in (allowing for the setting of @@global.secure_file_priv) and you should change `yrcolname` to an appropriate value.